# Firebase Dynamic Link always shows preview page when app is not installed

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I have an React Native app with dynamic links. The dynamic link opens correctly when the app is installed. But when the app is not installed I would like to open a specific website and not the AppStore preview page.
Regarding to the react-native-firebase docs the "setFallbackUrl" method on iOS should handle this. But it's not working at all...

I'm using react-native-firebase 5.2.1

Here is my code for creating the dynamic link:

```
const link = new firebase.links.DynamicLink(`fallback-url&para=?${someparams}`, 'my.test.link')
        .android.setPackageName('packagename')
        .ios.setBundleId('packagename')
        .ios.setFallbackUrl('fallback-url')
        .ios.setCustomScheme('customscheme')
        .android.setFallbackUrl('fallback-url')
        .analytics.setCampaign('title')

    firebase.links()
        .createShortDynamicLink(link, 'UNGUESSABLE')
        .then((url) => {
            this.setState({ link: url })
        });
```

Is something missing in my code or is there a specific rule like that the fallback url should be https... or whatever?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

According to official documentation, you should specify the URL patterns allowed in your fallback links in the url patterns Whitelist.

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create